# linux script, standard directory locations

Tags: linux, directory, location, conventions

I am trying to write a bash script to do a task, I have done pretty well so far, and have it working to an extent, but I want to set it up so it's distributable to other people, and will be opening it up as open source, so I want to start doing things the "conventional" way. Unfortunately I'm not all that sure what the conventional way is.

Ideally I want a link to an in depth online resource that discusses this and surrounding topics in depth, but I'm having difficulty finding keywords that will locate this on google.

At the start of my script I set a bunch of global variables that store the names of the dirs that it will be accessing, this means that I can modify the dir's quickly, but this is programming shortcuts, not user shortcuts, I can't tell the users that they have to fiddle with this stuff. Also, I need for individual users' settings not to get wiped out on every upgrade.

Questions:

Name of settings folder: ~/.foo/ -- this is well and good, but how do I keep my working copy and my development copy separate? tweek the reference in the source of the dev version?

If my program needs to maintain and update library of data (gps tracklog data in this case) where should this directory be? the user will need to access some of this data, but it's mostly for internal use. I personally work in cygwin, and I like to keep this data on separate drive, so the path is wierd, I suspect many users could find this. for a default however I'm thinking ~/gpsdata/ -- would this be normal, or should I hard code a system that ask the user at first run where to put it, and stores this in the settings folder? whatever happens I'm going ot have to store the directory reference in a file in the settings folder.

The program needs a data "inbox" that is a folder that the user can dump files, then run the script to process these files. I was thinking ~/gpsdata/in/  ?? though there will always be an option to add a file or folder to the command line to use that as well (it processed files all locations listed, including the "inbox")

Where should the script its self go? it's already smart enough that it can create all of it's ancillary/settings files (once I figure out the "correct" directory) if run with "./foo --setup" I could shove it in /usr/bin/ or /bin or ~/.foo/bin (and add that to the path) what's normal?

I need to store login details for a web service that it will connect to (using curl -u if it matters) plan on including a setting whereby it asks for a username and password every execution, but it currently stores it plane text in a file in ~/.foo/ -- I know, this is not good. The webservice (osm.org) does support oauth, but I have no idea how to get curl to use it -- getting curl to speak to the service in the first place was a hack. Is there a simple way to do a really basic encryption on a file like this to deter idiots armed with notepad?

Sorry for the list of questions, I believe they are closely related enough for a single post. This is all stuff that stabbing at, but would like clarification/confirmation over.

Answer (score 1):

> Name of settings folder: ~/.foo/ -- this is well and good, but how do I keep my working copy and my development copy separate?

Have a default of `~/.foo`, and an option (for example `--config-directory`) that you can use to override the default while developing.

> If my program needs to maintain and update library of data (gps tracklog data in this case) where should this directory be?

If your script is running under a normal user account, this will have to be somewhere in the user's home directory; elsewhere, you'll have no write permissions. Perhaps `~/.foo/tracklog` or something? Again, add a command line option, and also an option in the configuration file, to override this.

I'm not a fan of your `~/gpsdata` default; I don't want my home directory cluttered with all sorts of directories that programs created without my consent. You see this happen on Windows a lot, and it's really annoying. (Saved games in My Documents? Get out of here!)

> The program needs a data "inbox" that is a folder that the user can dump files, then run the script to process these files. I was thinking ~/gpsdata/in/ ?

As stated above, I'd prefer `~/.foo/inbox`. Also with command-line option and configuration file option to change this.

But do you really need an inbox? If the user needs to run the script manually over some files, it might be better just to accept those file names on the command line. They could just be processed wherever, without having to move them to a "magic" location.

> Where should the script its self go?

This is usually up to the packaging system of the particular OS you're running on. When installing from source, `/usr/local/bin` is a sensible default that won't interfere with package managers.

> Is there a simple way to do a really basic encryption on a file like this to deter idiots armed with notepad?

Yes, there is. But it's better not to, because it creates a false sense of security. Without a master password or something, secure storage is not possible! Pidgin, for example, explicitly stores passwords in plain text, so that users won't make any false assumptions about their passwords being stored "securely". So it's best just to store them in plain text, complain if the file is world-readable, and add a clear note to the manual to warn the user what's going on.

Bottom line: don't try to reinvent the wheel. There have been thousands of scripts and programs that faced the same issues; most of them ended up adopting the same conventions, and for good reasons. Look at what they do, and mimic them instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm doing my best to avoid reinventing the wheel (hence why I asked this question). Unfortunatly finding other scripts that do comparable tasks, and inspecting what they do is not a simple operation.

As for the magic location inbox, I fully intend on implementing both -- it already takes a list of files as arguments and takes them as inputs, this is for beginners so I can say "copy the stuff to A and double click on B"

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf).  I'm not sure how well followed it is, but it does provide some guidance.  In general, I try to use the following:

- `$HOME/.foo/` is used for user-specific settings - it is hidden
- `$PREFIX/etc/foo/` is for system-wide configuration
- `$PREFIX/foo/bin/` is for system-wide binaries

  - sym-links from `$PREFIX/foo/bin` are added to `$PREFIX/bin/` for ease of use
- `$PREFIX/foo/var/` is where *variable* data would live - this is where your input spools and log files would live

`$PREFIX` should default to `/opt/foo` even though almost everyone seems to plop stuff in `/usr/local` by default (thanks GNU!).  If someone wants to install the package in their home directory, then substitute `$HOME` for `$PREFIX`.  At least that is my take on how this should all work.